# In Jekyll can I nest Liquid tempting inside a tag?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have my site page titles and URLs inside a YAML file, *links.yml*:

```
siteLinks:
  - title: Home
    url: /index.md
  - title: About
    url: /about.md
```

I am trying to create a navigation bar which uses the titles and links from the YAML:

```
{% for link in site.data.links.siteLinks %}
  <a href="{% link link.url %}">{{link.title}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

However, I am getting an exception message when rendering:

```
Liquid Exception: Could not find document 'link.url' in tag 'link'. Make sure the document exists and the path is correct.
```

I am relatively new to Jekyll: how can I resolve the issue I am experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

Unless needed in another part of your code, you can simplify your data by removing the top-level `siteLinks`:

```
- title: Home
  url: /index.md
- title: About
  url: /about.md
```

Then your loop should be:

```
{% for link in site.data.links %}
  <a href="{{link.url}}">{{link.title}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```